# Bing Maps v8 - Invoke Click Event on PushPin

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

Once i load the Bing map with multiple pushpin with infobox. I have added click Here anchor tag on HTML with specific pushpin index to display infobox on javascript click event. Somehow it's not working for me.

I do see **[Invoke](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750279.aspx)** event is being supported in v8

Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/9dc4oxfk/2/

```js
var map, infobox;
  map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map('#myMap', {
    credentials: ''
  });

  //Create an infobox at the center of the map but don't show it.
  infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(map.getCenter(), {
    visible: false
  });

  //Assign the infobox to a map instance.
  infobox.setMap(map);

  //Create random locations in the map bounds.
  var randomLocations = Microsoft.Maps.TestDataGenerator.getLocations(5, map.getBounds());

  for (var i = 0; i < randomLocations.length; i++) {
    var pin = new Microsoft.Maps.Pushpin(randomLocations[i]);

    //Store some metadata with the pushpin.
    pin.metadata = {
      title: 'Pin ' + i,
      description: 'Discription for pin' + i
    };

    //Add a click event handler to the pushpin.
    Microsoft.Maps.Events.addHandler(pin, 'click', pushpinClicked);

    //Add pushpin to the map.
    map.entities.push(pin);
  }


function pushpinClicked(e) {
  //Make sure the infobox has metadata to display.
  if (e.target.metadata) {
    //Set the infobox options with the metadata of the pushpin.
    infobox.setOptions({
      location: e.target.getLocation(),
      title: e.target.metadata.title,
      description: e.target.metadata.description,
      visible: true
    });
  }
}

function showInfoboxByKey(Key) {

  //Look up the  pushpin by gridKey.
  var selectedPin = map.entities.get(gridKey);
  //Show an infobox for the cluster or pushpin.
  Microsoft.Maps.Events.invoke(selectedPin, "click");
}
```

```html
    <script type='text/javascript'
        src='http://www.bing.com/api/maps/mapcontrol?callback=GetMap'
        async defer></script>
 <div id="myMap" style="position:relative;width:600px;height:400px;"></div>
 <a href='javascript:void(0);' onclick='showInfoboxByKey(3);'> Click Here </a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is you haven't passed in any event arguments when you invoked the event. As such the event handler doesn't get past your if statement and thus doesn't do anything. See the documentation here and you will notice that you need to provide the event arguments: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt750279.aspx

That said, I'm not a fan of the approach being taken in your app here. If you simply want to get this working quick an easy, replace your invoke line of code with this:

```
pushpinClicked({e:{target: selectedPin }});
```

I highly recommend adding your pushpins to a layer and adding your click event to the layer. This greatly reduces the complexity of the event system and has a small performance boast.

Comment: Thanks for answer. I have updated my code to use as you suggest. Here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/9dc4oxfk/4/

Comment: I have asked another question, if you know the answer?https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44461347/bing-maps-v8-svg-inline-pushpin-not-trigger-correct-infobox