# Bing Maps v8 - SVG inline pushpin not trigger correct infobox

Tags: javascript, bing-maps

I am having issue with Bing Maps v8 with inline SVG string image for pushpin. I have added multiple pushpin with infobox using SVG inline image.

Once map is loaded with pushpin (https://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/9dc4oxfk/5/show/). I click pushpin #3 , #7 and #6, it always trigger pushpin #2. After I zoom in to map and try it again it works fine.

Here is jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pakpatel/9dc4oxfk/5

```
enter code here
```

Comment: your jsfiddle doesn't appear to work. No pushpins are appearing.

Comment: @rbrundritt i can see in chrome, edge and internet explorer browser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with the width and height setting of the svg icon element. Currently you sets `width="500" height="500"`. Try after changing it to small width and height `width="70" height="20"`